# java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver is not executable: /resources/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs

Tags: java, linux, selenium, jenkins, phantomjs

I am trying to run selenium UI test in headless mode in Jenkins(Unix). I am using the correct version of phantomJS for unix environment.

```
phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs
```

I get the above mentioned error. Any insight? I will provide more details if needed.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver is not executable: /resources/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the actual file needs to be executable in order to run. change file permissions to make it executable like:

```
chmod 755 /resources/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs
```

and then re-run. HTH

Comment: Yep, the problem went away after making the file executable.Thanks!