# How to use headless browser via Jmeter GUI

Tags: jmeter

I tried to use the all jmeter's drivers to create headless browser, but unfortunately without success. HtmlUnit Driver works, but doesn't run the javascript, when i run the both Chrome and PhantomJs drivers, i getting the Exception:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Browser has not been configured.  Please ensure at least 1 WebDriverConfig is created for a ThreadGroup.

Below my Phantom and Chrome configurations:
[image: The path to phantom js and chrome is correct[![][1]][1]]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looking into the error you're getting it seems that your [Chrome Driver Config](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ChromeDriverConfig/) and/or [PhantomJS Driver Config](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PhantomJSDriverConfig/) are **not enabled**, you need to make the Config element active via `Edit -> Toggle` menu or pressing `Ctrl+T`.

Be aware that you can run in fact any browser in headless mode, on Linux you can use [virtual framebuffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb) and on Windows you can just run JMeter as [LocalSystem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/services/localsystem-account) account. Check out [Headless Execution of Selenium Tests in Jenkins](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/headless-execution-selenium-tests-jenkins) guide for comprehensive instructions.

Also be informed that even in headless mode real browser footprint in terms of CPU and RAM usage will still be immense so I wouldn't recommend using real browsers for creating the main load, you should stick to JMeter's [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers instead and if needed use single real browser instance via WebDriver Sampler integration for client-side performance checks.

Comment: Of course the drivers were enabled, during the testing, it's just configuration screenshots. I have to use headless browsers for automation testing, i have to enable javascript. Another addition for my post, the full exception is :  java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: /root/apache-jmeter-5.0/C:/Users/Tesyolkin/Downloads/chromedriver_win32(1)/chromedriver.exe. Looks like there is an addition to my path  - "/root/apache-jmeter-5.0/". I don't know where it comes from

Comment: You're running your tests on Linux, aren't you? If yes, then why you're referring Windows versions of Chrome/PhantomJS executables?

Comment: Yes, my tests will run on Linux, but right now I'm opening the Jmeter client on Windows, just for checking the functionality. I mean that the jmeter installed on some Linux machine, but for opening  some browser(no matter headless or no), i should provide the path to executables in Windows. Am i right?

Comment: On Windows you need to provide path to Windows executable and on Linux for Linux. Neither ChromeDriver or PhantomJS is cross-platform

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself. If the machine with Jmeter on linux, you should give the permissions to run the executable:

chmod 755 "path to you driver executable file"

Thanks to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40556732/5279455